# 2013 Election Results

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

The election process is over, and now it is time to declare the winners:

[image: Mariano Suárez-Alvarez] [image: Todd Trimble]

Good luck in the new position, I'm sure that you'll prove to be a great addition to the community and its moderators!

On the same breath, I wanted to express my (and the community's) endless gratitude to the leaving [Anton Geraschenko](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1/anton-geraschenko) for founding this website, and for his endless work towards this project and community!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://mathoverflow.net/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5264199680786432/0).

Comment: Congratulations, Mariano and Todd!

Comment: Mariano and Todd -- Congratulations from me as well!

Comment: @Shog: Thanks for the edit. That's the second time I beat you to it. :-)

Comment: That's now *two* sites where you've beaten me to the announcement, Asaf! (Nicely done)

Comment: Congratulations for all candidates. It was a really hard election because all of our candidates were very good and could be excellent moderators.

Comment: @Andres: Dear Andres, I wish you the best successes in your life. I am really sorry that MathOverflow cannot use a wise moderator like you but I am sure that your very positive editorial actions continues at any condition.

Comment: @Todd: Dear Todd, I have two congratulations! First for you as a new moderator. I believe that it can be a really special event in the history of MathOverflow to have a moderator with a very soft and open minded manner like you. And second congratulations is mine for my exact foreseen about the result of election as a pseudo sociologist! I wish you to be always happy.

Comment: Thanks for the congratulations and good wishes!

Comment: @Todd: The diamond beside your name seems like a medal of honor! It is really beauty.

Comment: @Mariano: Dear Mariano, Congratulations. I don't know you personally because we had no direct conversation before but I am sure that you are one of the bests and completely qualified to be an excellent moderator. Best Regards.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who participated in the election, including those candidates who were not elected. It's great that we had such a wide pool of candidates, most of whom would have been excellent moderators, too.

Comment: Condolences... I mean, congratulations to the winners!

Comment: @Arturo At leat Mariano knew what he would be getting into.