# Anton's departure as moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

Does outgoing moderator [Anton Geraschenko](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1/anton-geraschenko) deserve our heartfelt thanks, or what?

Comment: Asaf already expressed this sentiment in a separate meta post (http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1040/), but I thought it deserved its own "question".

Comment: Thanks for the thanks! I wouldn't be as outgoing as I am were it not for the MO community.

Comment: I had told Anton a few months back that I'd like to buy him a drink or two should I chance to meet him, but I think he's gotten more such offers than would be good for his mathematics! But indeed, the community is hugely in debt to him.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: btw, now that you have a ♦, you can edit your comment even after 5 minutes have passed.

Comment: @AntonGeraschenko Ha! Thanks.

Comment: @AntonGeraschenko, that is almost the whole point of being a mod! :-)

Answer (score 84):

I think the answer is ... yes.

Comment: This tempts me to post an offsetting answer of "no" for purposes of liquidity- I'm prevented from doing so by impossibility of downvoting my own post.

Comment: @DanielMoskovich no worries, I'd be happy to downvote your answer for you :)

Answer (score -39):

For the purpose of offering an offsetting position:

NO

Comment: Now I'm tempted to post an answer "For the purposes of modality... Maybe!" :-)

Comment: How about "I don't know" or "No opinion"? :)

Comment: @Asaf: as there are more upvotes on the Yes answer than this one, we can (by Mathematician Logic (TM)) conclude that about 60% of MO users do not believe in the law of excluded middle.

Comment: @Willie: That's not Mathematical Logic (TM). It's statistics, which as D'Israeli said, is the worst kind of a lie!

Comment: @Asaf: not "Mathematical Logic", "[Mathematician Logic](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/mgonzale/bromas/jokes_math/jokes_math.html)"

Comment: @Willie: The eyes see, but the mind reads. ;-)

Comment: It's one thing to think A deserves a vote up and another to think that not-A deserves a vote down.  Maybe a vote up means that an answer is reasonable, and a vote down means that an answer is unreasonable.  But certainly there are many debates where one can think A is a reasonable opinion without thinking that not-A is an unreasonable opinion. :-)